# Interporlating multiple columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation, linear-interpolation

I have a dataframe with multiple columns

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Date': [1930, 1931, 1932, 1933,1934],
'File1': [np.nan, 72, 58, 280, 958],
'File2': [22, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 13],
'File3': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 18, 137],
'File4': [np.nan, 552, 1377, 280, np.nan],
'File5': [45, 1252, np.nan, 1841, np.nan],
})
```

I want to perform interpolation  on the entire dataframe (using FillMean for example). However the files have different start and end dates. So I need to say interpolate (using FillMean ) between the first value and the last value of that file (It should not interpolate before the start date (first value in  the file) or after the end date(last value in the file)

For example for:

- file 1 no interpolation should take place since there are no missing
  value after the start date.
- File 2 there should be interpolation as there are blank value between start date and end date
  And so on…

expected output

```
   Date  File1  File2  File3   File4   File5
0  1930    NaN  22.00    NaN   280.0    45.0
1  1931   72.0  19.75    NaN   552.0  1252.0
2  1932   58.0  17.50    NaN  1377.0  1546.5
3  1933  280.0  15.25   18.0   280.0  1841.0
4  1934  958.0  13.00  137.0     NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) with parameter `limit_are='inside'`:

```
df = df.interpolate(limit_are='inside').mask(df.bfill().isna())
print (df)
   Date  File1  File2  File3   File4   File5
0  1930    NaN  22.00    NaN     NaN    45.0
1  1931   72.0  19.75    NaN   552.0  1252.0
2  1932   58.0  17.50    NaN  1377.0  1546.5
3  1933  280.0  15.25   18.0   280.0  1841.0
4  1934  958.0  13.00  137.0     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: this seemed to work at first glance but when i checked now just to confirm it seems the interpolation is working for the start period(it starts interpolating at the right time) but for the end it goes beyond the end date. For example file 4 & 5 is supposed to end in 1933

Comment: @Tamarie - Can you add expected output DataFrame for verify all columns?

Comment: added expected output at the end of the question

Comment: @Tamarie - thank you, it seems `(limit_are='inside'` add values to end, so added [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) for replace values to missing by last `NaN`s